# White blink during background animation

Tags: html, css

Hello guys it's my first time here so I wanna to welcome everybody. I have a problem with background images. I try write animation that is responsible for displaying several photos in the background. Unfortunately, when you jump from one photo to another, there is a white blink. How to fix it? I tried to set "border-style: none;" but to no avail.

That's my css code:

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.background{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-style: none;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation: animacja1 150s linear infinite 0s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
}

@keyframes animacja1 {
  0%{
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
  }12.5%{
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
  }25%{
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
  }37.5%{
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
  }50%{
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
  }62.5%{
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
  }75%{
    background-image: url(../images/7.jpg);
  }87.5%{
    background-image: url(../images/8.jpg);
  }100%{
}
}
```

Comment: check the last snippet of the accepted answer. you need to load the image initially to avoid the blink effect

Comment: It's work but now effect of animation is gone. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: show me how you did it here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @keyframes animacja1 {
  0%{
    content: url(../images/1.jpg);
  ...
  }100%{
}

html:before {
  content:""; background:url(../images/1.jpg),url(../images//2.jpg),...}

Comment: *{...}
body{...}

html{..} I left without changes

Comment: try to share a full code in the link I gave you so I can better see it and run it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2t7asv4j/

Comment: use as background: https://jsfiddle.net/rp07egh8/

Comment: Thats work but on Firefox css animation doesnt work